# Python requests to connect to Paypal

Tags: python, paypal, python-requests

I'm trying to use requests module to use paypal oauth but for some reason. The client id value is set as key and secret is set as value.

Please let me know what is wrong?

```
r = requests.post('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',data={'Ae19ErLh':'EHRcOhCsBUqgNQgp5-','grant_type':'credentials','content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})]


>>> r.content
'{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Invalid client credentials"}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those should be headers, not data.

But there is a [Python library for the Paypal API](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python) which will probably be easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

I would say PayPal SDK library pulls not necessary dependencies:
    libssl-dev
    libffi-dev

Root access might be needed to install those packages. Not every developer has it.

In my opinion in order to have better portable code and have easier maintenance it is much better to use native Python tools for that to save yourself from future headaches. Also there are chances that you will need same requests library dependency elsewhere.

In general what you need to tune - is send:

grant_type - as parameter.

'Accept': 'application/json', 'Accept-Language': 'en_US', 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' - as header.

Also you need to authenticate.

Request could look like this:

requests.post(paypal_url, headers = headers, params = params, auth = HTTPBasicAuth(paypal_userid, paypal_secret))

Function I wrote for myself and detailed example can be found [here](http://www.linuxadmin.lt/python-paypal-rest-api-get-authentication-token/).

Answer (score 0):

Old question but for those that need to access the PayPal API in Python / Django:

```
import requests
from django.conf import settings
```

...

```
headers = {"Accept": "application/json",
           "Accept-Language": "en_US"}

data = {"grant_type":"client_credentials"}

req = requests.post('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
                   headers = headers,
                   data = data,
                   auth=(settings.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID, settings.PAYPAL_SECRET))

req_json = req.json()

#use this for the API requests
paypal_token = req_json["access_token"]
```